# Possible to draw Boxplot using quartiles only?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

Sorry about the informality but I am posting from my phone here.

Is it possible to draw/sketch a boxplot only using the values of quartiles? For example, minimum is 1, max is 10 lower quartile is 2 and upper quartile is 6, with median 4.

Comment: If the background color is white:  `BoxWhiskerChart[
 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
  100], {"Basic", {"Whiskers", White}}]`.

Comment: Or is your question "How do I estimate the minimum and maximum given the 3 quartiles?"

Comment: `BoxWhiskerChart[{ 1, 2, 4, 6, 10 }]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `"BoxRange"` method option to `BoxWhiskerChart` provides a few ways of computing the key statistics for drawing the box-whisker chart.  In the most general form, when given a function `f`, it applies `f` to the data to compute the min, max, median, and quartiles.  By using the identity function, you can just pass in the precomputed values as the data to `BoxWhiskerChart` and use them instead of the normal calculations.

`BoxWhiskerChart[{1, 2, 4, 6, 10}, Method -> {"BoxRange" -> (# &)}]`

[image]

Comment: Neat trick! `BoxWhiskerChart[{1, 2, 4, 6, 10}, Method -> {"BoxRange" -> Identity}]` also works of course.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that when I wrote "identity function", but felt that in this case `#&` was more illustrative, since it's clearer that something is being passed in as opposed to being a special value.  And it's a feature, not a trick. :-)

Comment: in version 9, `BoxWhiskerChart[{1, 2, 4, 6, 10}]` , `BoxWhiskerChart[{1, 2, 4, 6, 10}, Method -> {"BoxRange" -> (#&)}]`, `BoxWhiskerChart[{1, 2, 4, 6, 10}, Method -> {"BoxRange" -> Quartiles}]` all give the same output.

Comment: On a related note, I don't see any option to put it to `horizontal`?? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: `BarOrigin -> Left`?