# BoxWhiskerChart with summary statistics

Tags: probability-or-statistics, charts

I would like to duplicate a BoxWhiskerChart, such as this:

[image]

but I do not have access to the full dataset that generated it.  I'm happy to type in by hand summary statistics (such as mean, 25%, 75%, etc.), but cannot see how do to that given the raw function call requires a full data set.

In short, for the above I would be happy to enter by hand data of the following sort:

`BoxWhiskerChart[{{.3,.4,.55,.65,.9},{.1,.2,.5,.55,.6}}]`

but of course this is not the proper format.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The following Q&A is strongly related; the answer there contains the same approach proposed by @kglr below and some explanation: [Possible to draw Boxplot using quartiles only?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/possible-to-draw-boxplot-using-quartiles-only)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Method` suboption `"BoxRange" -> Identity`:

```
summaryStats = {{.3, .4, .55, .65, .9}, {.1, .2, .5, .55, .6}};

BoxWhiskerChart[summaryStats, Method -> {"BoxRange" -> Identity}]
```

[image]

**Related Q/As:**

1. [Tuning BoxWhiskerChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147750/125)
2. [Possible to draw Boxplot using quartiles only?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/182586/125)
3. [How to access box-and-whisker specifications from custom ChartElementFunction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121462/125)

Comment: Oh... gee... I searched for such an option.  But once again (this is getting *ridiculous*!), the great @kglr saves the day.  ($\checkmark$)